# How to create checked Set with one (or more elements) in simple way?

Tags: java, set

How to create checked Set with one (or more elements)

I have some Objects of type A and I want to create checked Set with all these objects

```
A element1; //not null
A element2; //not null; optional
```

my solution:

```
Set<A> s = new HashSet<>(1);
a.add(element1);
a.add(element2); //optional
```

Q: **Is there any standard util class to create it in simple way?**

Something like

```
   List<A> l = java.util.Arrays.asList(element1);
   List<A> l = java.util.Arrays.asList(element1, element2); // optional
```

but for `Set`

Answer (score 0):

In JDK-8:

```
Stream.of(element1, element2).collect(toSet());
```

or to guarantee the type of set returned:

```
Stream.of(element1, element2).collect(toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

if not on JDK8 yet then the best option is probably:

```
new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(element1, element2));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<A> s = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(element1, element2));
```